# Custom CSS style for YouTube Stream Chat iframe via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, youtube

I embed the YouTube Streaming livechat into a Website with a simple iframe. There are some elements in the chat layout that i would like to customize like colors. To reach this, i was trying to add a javascript code to my website and append the css style into the head of the iframe. None of the following example didn't work and i can't figure out why, it just changes nothing. The only that i can see is that the style won't be added to the head of the iframe, no console error Messages or simlar. I would be thankful for any hint where my mistake is.

My testet **embeds**:

```
<iframe name="chat_iframe" id="chat_iframe" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="675" src="https://gaming.youtube.com/live_chat?v=0x0C6F8iuJA&theme=dark&embed_domain=stream-team.eu" width="320"></iframe>
```

*Javascript* example that didn't work for me (Into my Website inside the footer)

**Example 1:**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var head = jQuery("#chat_iframe").contents().find("head");
    var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
              '.paper-icon-button-0{display:none};' +
              '</style>';
    jQuery(head).append(css);
</script>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var $head = $("chat_iframe").contents().find("head");                
    $head.append($("<link/>", 
    { rel: "stylesheet", href: "https://stream-team.eu/chat.css", type: "text/css" }));
</script>
```

**Example 3:**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink.href = "https://stream-team.eu/chat.css"; 
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
    frames['chat_iframe'].document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
</script>
```

As **CSS** I tried several ways for testing like

```
.paper-icon-button-0 {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: can you put working link (This video is unavailable.)

Comment: I'm not pretty sure why this message is appearing, i didn't have it on my website, but i did see it for some time ago. What i can do is creating a small test stream video, that maybe could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security restrictions you can only access the contents of an iframe with JavaScript if the iframe is showing content from the same domain the JavaScript is running from.

Otherwise, what would stop a hacker from loading some site in an iframe and stealing a user's login information when the user attempts to login or stealing their credit card number when they attempt to make a purchase?

Comment: So what you would say is, that i haven't any chance to customize the css code of a iframe if the webpage of the source is not on my webserver?

Comment: Exactly. Now whether you could write some code that runs on your server and acts as a reverse proxy to inject some HTML is another question.

Comment: Thank you, saved me a lot of time to try more javascript ways.